# first-child / last-child different hover styles

Tags: css

I want to make the gradient effect with the darker side on the left for `Previous` and the darker side on the right for `Next`. Here is what I tried so far: https://jsfiddle.net/jn87640p/4/

What am I missing?

```css
.calnav {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  color: #000;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: white;
}

.calnav:first-child:hover {
  background: #537d8d;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(33, 21, 32, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(33, 21, 32, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(33, 21, 32, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#211520', endColorstr='#00ffffff', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 */
}

.calnav:last-child:hover {
  background: #537d8d;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(253, 253, 253, 0) 1%, rgba(37, 26, 36, 1) 98%, rgba(33, 21, 32, 1) 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(253, 253, 253, 0) 1%, rgba(37, 26, 36, 1) 98%, rgba(33, 21, 32, 1) 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(253, 253, 253, 0) 1%, rgba(37, 26, 36, 1) 98%, rgba(33, 21, 32, 1) 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00ffffff', endColorstr='#211520', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 */
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid calnav_head">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="calnav"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left pull-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> Previous</div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 calnav_head_title">
      <h1>July - 2017</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="calnav">Next <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, I put it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any reason why you wouldn't want to apply the formatting to the  links and lose the contained divs?

Example:

```
a.calnav {
    display:block; // or display:inline-block depending on your need
    font-size: 1.3em;
    color: #000;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background: white;
}
```

Then just add a prev/next class name to each (`a.calnav.prev {}`) ?

Comment: That does not answer the question *first-child / last-child different hover styles. What am I missing?*. However, it provides a good alternative approach. +1.

Comment: Glad to help... btw, I'd look at Racil Hilan's answer as well and review child selectors. You were referencing both the same elements in your CSS. My own personal preference with something like this would be the different class tags, as I'd shown, since it would likely be the case that the Prev/Next links/buttons would be tied to some kind Javascript function instead of using href attributes to go backward or forward (as in the case of an image slideshow), so the .prev/.next class tags would make it easier to assign associated JS click actions.

Comment: Racil, you're right, and your follow-up comment made it in just a little faster than my follow-up, which mentioned your note :-) .... I hadn't noted the main   problem, which you pointed  out in your response.

Answer (score 2):

First off, your HTML contains errors. You should not put `<div>` inside `<a>`. Anyway, the issue is because each of your elements with the `calnav` class is the only child of its parent. You need to apply the class to the higher level.

Also your CSS has some minor errors. Here is the fix:

```css
.calnav {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  color: #000;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: white;
}

.calnav:first-child:hover {
  background: #537d8d;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(33, 21, 32, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(33, 21, 32, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(left, rgba(33, 21, 32, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  dfilter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#211520', endColorstr='#00ffffff', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 */
}

.calnav:last-child:hover {
  background: #537d8d;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(253, 253, 253, 0) 1%, rgba(37, 26, 36, 1) 98%, rgba(33, 21, 32, 1) 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(253, 253, 253, 0) 1%, rgba(37, 26, 36, 1) 98%, rgba(33, 21, 32, 1) 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(253, 253, 253, 0) 1%, rgba(37, 26, 36, 1) 98%, rgba(33, 21, 32, 1) 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  dfilter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00ffffff', endColorstr='#211520', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 */
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid calnav_head">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-md-3 calnav">
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left pull-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> Previous</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 calnav_head_title">
      <h1>July - 2017</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 calnav">
      <a href="#">Next <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```